# Server-side calculations on Firestore records. What's the best way?

Tags: firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

We program an app (Android, iOS) that works with Firebase authentication. We use Cloud Firestore as our database.  Users log in and make some settings. Now we have to do some complex calculations (based on the locations of the users and some other filters) with the Cloud Firestore data sets and inform the users later with push-notifications. However, we found that Cloud Firestore is very very limited in terms of queries. In addition, we cannot make server-side calculations.

So my question is: How can we handle the problem best?

A first approach would be to use an additional server and run the calculations (with a Java program) on it. The connection would then run via a snapshot listener that keeps all the data on the additional server synchronized (unfortunately somewhat expensive, due to the billing by documents).

A second approach would be to use other databases, such as Cloud Datastore or Google Cloud Spanner (we don't know the prices). However, the simplicity of the database connection would be lost and the implementation would be much more complicated.

We assume that we will acquire many users in the future and that the calculations can become very complex. However, we need a good price/performance ratio at the beginning because we have little capital available.

Do you have any tips for us, which way would be the best?

Comment: You can use Cloud Functions to process the server-side calculations.  See Extend with Cloud Functions in the Cloud Firestore documentation.

With regards to querying, can you give some examples of the queries that you are trying to achieve?  Cloud Firestore and Cloud Datastore have almost identical data structures, so ther's likely to be little to be gained from using Cloud Datastore over Cloud Firestore.